# Tkinter Button not changing from entry

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Just messing around with `tkinter` for the first time and I dont know why my buttons are not working. Basically the `input_grade` is supposed to get a `value` from `entry_for_grades` which is `quiz_amount` and just print it on the same `window` but I keep getting back 0

I looked up and thought I was suppose to use `lambda` but it keeps giving me 0 regardless of what I have in entry and press ok

```py
from tkinter import *
quiz_amount = IntVar()

def quiz():
    quiz_window = Tk()
    window(quiz_window)
    quiz_window.title('Quiz Grades')
    width = quiz_window.winfo_width()
    height= quiz_window.winfo_height()
    quiz_window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(width, height))
    entry_for_grades = Entry(quiz_window, textvariable=quiz_amount)
    entry_for_grades.pack()
    grade_amount = Button(quiz_window,text='Ok',command=lambda:see_text(quiz_window)).place(x=85,y=60)   
def see_text(window):
    Label(window,text=float(quiz_amount.get())).place(x=85,y=90)
```

Comment: You can't create Tkinter Vars until after you've called `Tk()` - I'm surprised this isn't causing an error, I guess something's changed since the version I use.

Comment: You are using this to make several windows, aren't you? The problem here is the IntVar is associated with the first window you created and can't be used in others. You need to use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk` to make additional windows, then you can use the IntVar in any of them.

Comment: It would be best to [give a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and made it [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (I think) and it works fine for me.

Here is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *


def quiz(quiz_window):
    # window(quiz_window)
    quiz_window.title('Quiz Grades')
    width = quiz_window.winfo_reqwidth()
    height= quiz_window.winfo_reqheight()
    quiz_window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(width, height))
    entry_for_grades = Entry(quiz_window, textvariable=quiz_amount)
    entry_for_grades.pack()
    grade_amount = Button(quiz_window,text='Ok',command=lambda:see_text(quiz_window)).place(x=85,y=60)
def see_text(window):
    Label(window,text=float(quiz_amount.get())).place(x=85,y=90)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    quiz_window = Tk()
    quiz_amount = IntVar()
    quiz(quiz_window)
    quiz_window.mainloop()
```

The only problem I can think of is, like `Novel` said, you are using more than one `Tk()` window and trying to pass variables between these windows.

You should almost never use more than one `Tk()` window since you cannot pass information between two `Tk()` windows. Instead use `TopLevel()` windows, information can flow freely between `Tk()` and `TopLevel()` windows.